# Restrict access to single IP only

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform

In `Google Cloud Platform` I'm trying to add a Firewall rule to my servers until they go live so they are only accessible from a single IP-address, for intance `192.0.2.1` (then I will remove the rule for go live). I see 2 ways of doing it:

1. **Allow ONLY** from IP **=** *192.0.2.1*
2. **Deny** from IP **!=** *192.0.2.1*

But looking at how the firewall rules work in `GCP`, it just doesn't seem possible:

- The **Allow ONLY** logic doesn't exist so rule [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLybb.png) can't be implemented
- The **!=** operator doesn't exist so rule [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnH8d.png) can't be implemented

**Is there a way to add a firewall rule (without changing existing rules) that restricts access only to a single IP-address in GCP?**

Following comments and replies, I'm trying the following rules:

[image]

and still, I'm able to ping/HTTP my instance from a different IP address :(

and these rules are listed in my `default` network:

[image]

which my instance is part of, so it should be working:

[image]

Comment: DENY from all, and the Allow from the IP you want

Comment: Very useful Post (y).

Answer (score 3):

You can allow traffic only from your IP address 192.0.2.1 by setting the Source IP range as : 192.0.2.1/32, so that only this address will be allowed as source IP.

Playing with Priority numbers, If you set another firewall rule with a deny from all with a higher value but lower value than the already existing one then you will just have to remove those two rules before going live.

To summarize the firewall rules (saying rule 1000 already exists):

```
10 - allow traffic from 192.0.2.1/32 to port tcp/80  
11 - deny from all traffic to port tcp/80  
1000 - allow traffic from all (0.0.0.0/0) to port tcp/80
```

More info at GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls).
I hope this helps

Comment: I'm trying something similar (see update in question), but it doesn't work (it's been added over 10 minutes ago, so I don't think it's firewall update delay that's causing this)

Comment: you have set targets tags on your rules, and each rules has a different target tag so they don't compete on priority matters as they don't have the same destination scope. put the same target tag on each rule and make sure that target tag is present on the instances you want to reach. Or select All instances on the network as targets if it applies.

Comment: Hi, any feedback on this ?

Comment: Very useful answer (y).